# Please identify these two kinds of Lego bricks (circa 1990's)

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

I recently bought a lot of Lego that was mostly 1990's bricks, and I had a few things I couldn't identify.  One I found on Bricklink, but the other two are baffling me. Here is the first one, a different sort of hinged plate that I hadn't seen before:
[image]
[image]

You would think these would be "modified plates," but I couldn't find them.
Even stranger are these pieces (two varieties):
[image]
These obviously allow for perpendicular placement of other pieces, and again I would think they were modified plates, but they aren't, at least in Bricklink.

I'm most curious to see how these pieces were used in sets.
Thank you!

Comment: The top one is https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3640#T=C and corresponding male part. I remember having a dump truck which used one of these (in black) as the base, allowing it to bend in the middle.

Comment: The white stand was also used in a police set for like a flag pole. And the hinge was used as a truck and trailer set that I had. (Still have not pieces, but I don't think I have the instructions that go with. So I can't tell you set numbers... sorryz)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first two are:

[Hinge Plate 2 x 4 with Articulated Joint - Male](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3639&in=S)

[image]

[Hinge Plate 2 x 4 with Articulated Joint - Female](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3640&in=S)

[image]

They are still used in modern sets sometimes.

---

The last two are called "bracket" pieces. They have not appeared in any recent sets.

[Bracket 2 x 3 - 1 x 3 (Train Signal Stand)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4169&in=S)

[image]

[Bracket 2 x 2 - 1 x 4](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2422&in=S)

[image]

Comment: Wow, and the 1x3 "Train Signal Stand" was only in ONE set in White! (The 6828 Twin-Winged Spoiler).  Thanks to all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the [left bracket](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2422&idColor=0#T=P&C=0) on [Swooshable](http://swooshable.com/snot?degree=90&page=2), a website that collects SNOT building techniques (I filtered by degree of 90). As you can guess, it was used for attaching things sideways, and appeared in 13 sets from 1987 to 1999.

Swooshable doesn't list the other piece, but Bricklink categorized the first one as "[Bracket](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=4)", which led me to the second piece, a [train signal stand](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4169#T=P). It appeared in sets from 1980 to 1988.