# Which Lego brick number is this? 1 x 3 connected vertically to a base

Tags: part-identification

Please can someone help me to identify the brick in the picture. Thanks.
[image: white 1 x 3 connected vertically to a base]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please identify these two kinds of Lego bricks (circa 1990's)](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8831/please-identify-these-two-kinds-of-lego-bricks-circa-1990s)

Comment: They're the same piece, but is there **any** way someone could make that connection with such a generic question?

Comment: We don't have a clear policy on whether similar part-identification questions are duplicates.  https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/508/6174  Unless folks happen to do an image-based search it seems unlikely normal users would have much chance of realizing they're making a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

It's part 4169 [Bracket 2 x 3 - 1 x 3 (Train Signal Stand)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4169)